# Javascript: Replacing Characters in String from keyCode event

Tags: javascript

I'm programming out a simple Hangman Game. A random word is selected from the wordBank, and then that wordLength determines the placeholder string of underscores. For example, 'dog' will show up as '_ _ _'.

I want the letters to replace the underscores when they are pressed, but for some reason when this happends, an extra underscore is added. So if I press 'd' on my keyboard, the placeholder goes from '_ _ _' to 'd _ _'. Then, when I press 'o', the word goes to 'do _ _ '. Is there a reason for this extra underscore?

```
// Game Variables

var remainingGuesses = 12;
var wins = 0;
var losses = 0;
var wordBank = ['caat', 'dog', 'tiger'];

// Select Random Word from Array

var word = wordBank[Math.floor(Math.random(2) * wordBank.length)];
var wordLength = word.length;


// Create Placeholders Based on Word Length

var placeholders = new Array(wordLength + 1).join( '_ ' );

// Captures Key Clicks

document.onkeyup = function(event) {
var userGuess = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();


// Check Word with Letter

    if (word.indexOf(userGuess) > -1) {
        alert('correct!');
        placeholders = placeholders.replace(placeholders[(word.indexOf(userGuess))], userGuess);
}
else {
    alert('wrong');
    remainingGuesses--;
}

console.log(placeholders);
console.log(word);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you are actually doing here,

1) Make a string called `placeholders` consisting of underscores **and spaces**
2) Check if a user choice exists at a given index in a word.
3) Replace a part of the `placeholders` string based on the index of that letter in the word.

The faulty assumption is that the characters in the `word` string match the characters in the `placeholder` string. They do not, in fact, there are double the characters so the indices will begin to mismatch. You will have the expected behavior for the first letter, and then not for every letter afterwards.

For example:

```
word = "dog" // 3 characters
placeholders = "_ _ _ " // 6 characters
```

A better approach would be to separate your logic from your display. One way to do this (without going full on object oriented) would be to have a word string, like you do, but also a corresponding array of display values which you initialize to false

```
word = "dog"
display = [false, false, false]

// and this is what you return to your user:

function makeDisplayString (word, display) {
  display.map(function(el, idx) { return el ? word[idx] : "_" }).join(" ");
}

makeDisplayString("dog", [false, true, false])
// => "_ o _"
```

If the user makes a choice, you replace the false value with true and run the same function to update your display.